# Static method return base class instance

Tags: c#, reflection

I have the following classes:

```
//some base class
public abstract class MyObject<T>{

      public static T FromObject(object anotherObject){
       var t = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
       //  some reflection logic here
       return t;
  }     
}

public class Product: MyObject<Product>{
}

public class ProductCart: MyObject<ProductCart>{
  public ICollection<Product> Products{get;set;}
}

public class Basket: ProductCart{
  public int BasketId{get;set;}
}

public class Order: ProductCart{
  public int OrderId{get;set;}
}
```

So now I could build my model like this:

```
var products = serviceContext.Products.Select(Product.FromObject).ToList(); // no problem here

var basket = Basket.FromObject(serviceContext.Basket); // problem is here - instance of ProductCart is returned

var order = Order.FromObject(serviceContext.Order); // same problem, instance of ProductCart
```

Is there a way somehow to solve it and get converted Basket and Order instead of base ProductCart?

The goal is:

```
 var basket = Basket.FromObject(serviceContext.Basket); // return instance of Basket inherited from ProductCart
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change the class definitions, you can pass along the type to `ProductCart`, like so:

```
public class ProductCart<T> : MyObject<T> { }
public class Basket : ProductCart<Basket> { }
public class Order : ProductCart<Order> {}
```

In your definition you tell `Basket.FromObject` to explicitly return `ProductCart`s (by inheriting from `MyObject<ProductCart>`).

And if you're unable to change the inherit tree, you can choose to hide the original method (or place it in a factory):

```
public class Basket : ProductCart
{
    public int BasketId { get; set; }

    public Basket FromObject(object anotherObject)
    {
        return MyObject<Basket>.FromObject(anotherObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! I think the first part (changing the class definition) is the solution. It looks like it works now!

Answer (score 0):

That's because `Basket` is a `MyObject<ProductCart>`, and not a `MyObject<Basket>`.

If you don't want to redefine your hierarchy, you should define the return type of the static method according to the object you pass, like in this example:

```
using System;

public abstract class MyObject<T> {

    public static TOtherObject FromObject<TOtherObject>(TOtherObject anotherObject) where TOtherObject : MyObject<T> {
        var newOtherTypeInstance = Activator.CreateInstance<TOtherObject>();
        //  some reflection logic here
        return newOtherTypeInstance;
    }
}

public class ProductCart : MyObject<ProductCart> {
}

public class Basket : ProductCart {
    public int BasketId { get; set; }
}

public class Order : ProductCart {
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
}

class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Order o = new Order();
        var basket = Basket.FromObject(o);
    }

}
```

Of course, at this point the actual implementation of the comment "some reflection logic here" could get much more complicated :)